# Problems with jQuery.Masonry

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem. When the page loads are placed photos are not, and are superimposed on each other.

**CSS:**

```
 body {background: #fefefe; color:#333; line-height:200%;}
.item {
    float:left /* ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО задаем блокам float */; 
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function ImagesStart(id) {
    var Images = [
        "photes/сайт002",
        "photes/сайт003",
        "photes/сайт004",
        "photes/сайт005",
        "photes/сайт006",
        ];
    for (var i = 0; i < Images.length; i++) {
        $("#" + id).append("<img id = '" + i + "' src = '" + Images[i] + "мал.jpg'class = 'item' onmouseover = 'over(this)' onmouseout = 'out(this)'>")
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ImagesStart("container");
    $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        singleMode: false,
        resizeable: true,
        //isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
    });
});
```

And screenshot.

[image]

If you boot to change the size of the browser window, things are fine. What's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`imagesLoaded`](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html) plugin, which basically delays operation on `window.load`, i.e. after all assets are loaded:

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.box'
  });
});
```

To achieve this, you shouldn't DOM-inject images via js, but better provide them into original HTML document better.